# How can I fix hook dependency arrays?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a demo app and I have a controlled search input. I am trying to debounce the onChange event to not trigger the API fetch function on each stroke. It works, but I get a warning about the dependency array:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'

[...]

const searchForMovies = (str) => {
    fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US&query=${str}&page=1&include_adult=false`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setMovies({movies: data.results}));
}

const handleChange = event => {
    const searchTerm = event.target.value
    setSearch({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    debounceSearch(searchTerm);
}

const debouncedSearch = useCallback(
    debounce((str) => searchForMovies(str), 500), []
);
```

It works, but I get a `React Hook useCallback received a function whose dependencies are unknown. Pass an inline function instead` error. According to the documentation, I am supposed to pass the dependencies to the last array, but adding either `debounce`, `searchForMovies` or `str` results in an error. How exactly am I supposed to handle the dependency array to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

create the function outside of your component

```
const debouncedSearchForMovie = debounce((str) => searchForMovies(str), 500)
...
const debouncedSearch = useCallback(
    () => debouncedSearchForMovie(str), [debouncedSearchForMovie, str]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're trying to invoke the return value of the debounce function, rather than the function itself.

note the difference between:

```
useCallback(() => myFunction(), [dependency]); // function to invoke.
```

and

```
useCallback(myFunction(), [dependency]); // this function has already been invoked.
```